# Grouping and summing last (by date) values in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example, there is a table with data:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|    date    |    account    | currency |  sum  |
-------------------------------------------------
| 2020-03-02 | EUR account 1 |   EUR    | 12000 |
| 2020-03-01 | EUR account 2 |   EUR    |  3000 |
| 2020-03-06 | USD account 1 |   USD    |  1234 |
| 2020-01-02 | GBP account 1 |   GBP    |  6800 |
| 2019-11-21 | EUR account 1 |   EUR    |  3584 |
| 2019-06-15 | EUR account 1 |   EUR    | 86874 |
| 2018-02-05 | USD account 1 |   USD    | 12121 |
```

SQL request to the data have to select last values and group it by currency. Resulted table should have next view:

```
--------------------
| currency |  sum  |
--------------------
|   EUR    | 15000 |
|   USD    |  1234 |
|   GBP    |  6800 |
```

Please suggest, how do make this request in SQLite correctly?

Comment: could it be multiple rows for the same account for the same date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` window function to select the last entry for each `account` and then aggregate:

```
select t.currency, sum(t.`sum`) `sum` 
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by account order by date desc) rn
  from tablename
) t 
where t.rn = 1
group by t.currency
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kUg4C9TjasCxdzN9JfDCd3/1).
Results:

```
| currency | sum   |
| -------- | ----- |
| EUR      | 15000 |
| GBP      | 6800  |
| USD      | 1234  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select t.currency, sum(t.sum)
from t
where strftime('%Y', t.date) = (select strftime('%Y', max(t2.date))
                                from t t2
                                where t2.account = t.account and t2.currency = t.currency
                               )
group by t.currency;
```

The `where` clause returns the last row for each account/currency combination (it is unclear whether or not currency is needed for this).  The query then aggregates these values.

Comment: This won't give correct result for `EUR`. You'll have to extract `year` from date and take `max`